# Retrieving an alt tag from a custom field

Tags: images, post-meta

I have a theme that uses TimThumb to generate thumbnail images on a gallery page. The problem is that image alt tags are not showing for each image on the main gallery pages, see here:

http://christinecraven.com/gallery/press

I've tried to generate the alt tag by adding a custom field in each post/ portfolio item, called "alt_tag" and then calling it in the category.php file in my theme:

`$alttag = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'alt_tag', true);`

```
<div class="imgHentry">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' ); ?> alt="<?php echo get_post_meta($att, 'alt_tag', true); ?>" 
    <div class="linkIcon" style="width:150px; height:150px;">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="goto-icon" style="width:150px; height:150px;"></a>
    </div>
</div><!-- .imgHentry -->
```

I found on this forum a similar question: [alt attributes not showing on pages](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39501/alt-attributes-not-showing-on-pages)

But unfortunately can't seem to cobble together a solution that works!

Comment: Where do you define `$att`? Also, the `alt` attribute needs to reside *within* the `img` tag, currently you are adding it outside of it. And the anchor is empty as well.

Answer (score 2):

The following ought to be much closer to what you want to achieve:

```
<div class="imgHentry">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="goto-icon">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(
            'thumbnail',
            array( 'alt' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'alt_tag', true ) )
       ); ?>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Sadly, it's not working. Shouldn't it be changing something though? I noticed in my original post, that yes I had made a typo in defining the $att, then tried to fix that, but that didn't seem to do anything. I wonder if I am in the correct template, but I can't imagine this isn't it. Any other ideas? Thank you!